# Continous Deployment in Drupal

Tags: deployment

I want to deploy my drupal project to higher environment - DEV -> QA --> Staging --> Production. So i understand the following moving parts

1) Drupal code - everything inside var/www/html. (this is automated using Jenkins once we check the code in GIT.)
2) Database (manual)
3) File system - we are using S3. (Manual).

I would like to do incremental push to higher environments - i do not want to dump the complete DB for every release.

If clients add few modules in Staging environment or do some setting changes in staging and production environment, how to retain the information when i do a next release? Please help.

Comment: Are you working on Drupal 8 project? or Drupal 7?

Comment: I suggest _never_ allowing the addition of modules in the server environment. The best way is adding them with Composer and committing that, then letting a CI server like Travis or Circle build the artifact and push it to the correct environment.

Comment: it is drupal 8.4

Comment: Kevin - thanks. It looks like the best option. How are dealing with files (PDFs , Docs etc). Currently we have files in S3. So first time i am good with syncing DB and files as a whole. But how about later releases. Is there an option to do incremental or delta pushes.